# Paypal Express Checkout : Creating subscriptions / recurring payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Using my Paypal account, I would like to add the following functionality to my new website

1. A checkout process that allows for payments via Paypal, Paypal Credit, or credit card (Google and Apple Pay would be nice)
2. The user should not leave my website
3. The checkout process should create a subscription / recurring payment
4. I would like to be notified if they cancel their sub or their payment is declined in subsequent months. (I'm assuming I can use IPN for this?)

I've played around with the Express Checkout form builder, but I don't see a way to specify "payment type". i.e. "Subscription"

Is this possible?

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution my requirements are identical to yours. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I was able to find the solution here https://gitter.im/paypal/paypal-checkout